# Table data overflow in print pdf

Tags: css, reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to print a PDF in my React application. I am using default print functionality to print pdf, not any library.

const printWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=907,height=863,left=0,top=0');
printWindow.print();

It works fine where there is limited. But when there is a huge data in the columns that overflows from the page. On the next page data overlaps on the headers of the column.

if in one columns it overflows the page. It breaks the formatting of other page well.